# How do I get the time of the previous '4 am'?

Tags: php, time

I would like to get the time in seconds (standard time() format) of the previous '4 am'.

My first attempt was: `mktime(4,0,0)`.

This works for every time of the day, except between 00:00 and 04:00, because than it will give the time of the next '4 am'.

- So how do I tackle this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$now    = new DateTime();
$fourAm = new DateTime('today 4am');

if ($now < $fourAm) {
    $time = strtotime('yesterday 4am');
} else {
    $time = $fourAm->getTimestamp();
}
```

Where `$time` is the timestamp of the "last 4am", regardless of what time it currently is.

**Edit:**

You could also do this without the `DateTime` objects, but I love that suite of classes, so I usually find any reason at all to use them. :-P

```
$now    = time();
$fourAm = strtotime('today 4am');

if ($now < $fourAm) {
    $time = strtotime('yesterday 4am');
} else {
    $time = $fourAm;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the time you have created is in the future, subtract one day.

Answer (score 0):

```
$date = strtotime('yesterday 4am');
```

Comment: Nice. I thought you had to do $results = strtotime("yesterday") + ( 60 * 60 *4 ); but that works even more elegantly.

Comment: strtotime() is a pretty amazing function.

Comment: He only wants yesterday if time is [0:00, 4:00)

Comment: @weston: Ah yes ok gotcha, my mistake -- I understood "last 4am" to mean "the one before *this* 4am" but he wants "the most recent 4am." I know strtotime() works with things like "last saturday" so I tried "last 4am" directly but no luck. Oh well.